# UITableView edit propagation to the model in MVVM

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I'm creating contact application learning how to use ReactiveCocoa with MVVM. I want to implement edit mode for the contact details table, so that when user taps Done button, I save these changes to the model.
Currently I have this structure:

- `List Of Contacts table` has VC and VM, each of its cells has custom view and VM.

When user taps on cell, I open details table.

- `Contact Details Table` has VC and VM, and again each cell has it's own custom view and VM.

When user taps Done button in `Contact Details` I can observe that in it's VM and construct new Contact object, but how can I notify `List Of Contacts` about this change?

I'm very confused with such architecture at the moment. So what is a common way to solve this user case in MVVM?

### Update:

I have updated the code and solved the problem, however I don't like how it is solved and the question is still up.

When user taps a cell on a contact list, new Details ViewModel is created. I pass a reference to the ContactsList ViewModel and index of selected contact in order to handle contact updates. (Later on if contact is changed, I change `contacts` property of contactsList view model)

ContactsList ViewController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushContactDetails"]) {
        STContactDetailsViewController *vc = (STContactDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.viewModel = [[STContactDetailsViewModel alloc] initWithContactIndex:self.viewModel.selectedContactIndex services:self.viewModel.services rootVM:self.viewModel];
    }
}
```

Details ViewModel:

```
-(instancetype)initWithContactIndex:(NSNumber *)contactIndex services:(id<STViewModelServices>)services rootVM:(STContactsListViewModel *)rootVM {

    //some initialisation 


    @weakify(self);
    self.saveChanges = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:[self executeChangeCheck] signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
        @strongify(self);
        return [self executeSaveChanges];
    }];
}

-(RACSignal *)executeSaveChanges {
    @weakify(self);
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

        @strongify(self);
        STContact *newContact = self.contact;

        //Update newContact with changed values

        NSMutableArray *newContacts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.rootVM.contacts];
        [newContacts replaceObjectAtIndex:_contactIndex withObject:newContact ];
        self.rootVM.contacts = newContacts;


        return [RACDisposable new];
    }];
}
```

When `contacts` property of ContactsList ViewModel is changed, its table reloads and I can see these changes when I get back from details view.

Moreover, In Details ViewController I handle view updates of its table if contact is changed and apply them when exit tableview edit mode.

Even though, everything works at the moment, I feel bad about passing reference of the ContactsList ViewModel to the Details ViewModel. I'd be grateful, if someone could show me the right way to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: Why do you create a new Contact object when user taps Done in Contact Details? Why not simply pass cell's VM to the contact details VC and modify it there?

Comment: I don't really understand you. There are 2 types of editable cells in Contact Details(phone and name). Isn't it easier to pass pack one contact object, rather then >2 cell VMs?

Comment: Please add a code snippet showing your problem, this will make it easier to help you.

Comment: @MichałCiuba, just updated the question with code snippets. Let me know if this is not enough to understand the problem